# SwiftUI gesture fall-through

Tags: ios, macos, swiftui

For [Flow](https://github.com/audiokit/flow), we had to use a single `Canvas` to render everything, and go down to platform-specific APIs. One of the problems was that gestures in SwiftUI don't seem to fall-through.

Suppose we've rendered the following UI using a `View` for each module:

[image: Data-flow graph example]

The modules should be dragged around, and the entire workspace zoomed with a pinch gesture.

The problem is that if you happen to pinch inside one of the modules, the zoom won't work because the module view gets the events.

**Is there a way that gestures/events can fall through to underlying views?**

The code I'd like would look something like this:

```
       ZStack(alignment: .topLeading) {
            // We need to use this WorkspaceView to manage pan and zoom
            // because SwiftUI doesn't give us coordinates along with a
            // magnification gesture!
            WorkspaceView(pan: $model.pan, zoom: $model.zoom)
            WiresView(model: model, nodeOffsets: nodeOffsets)
                .allowsHitTesting(false)
            ForEach(model.nodes) { node in
                // The problem here is that NodeView intercepts
                // events that should make their way to WorkspaceView.
                NodeView(model: $model,
                         node: $model.nodes[model.nodes.firstIndex(of: node)!],
                         nodeOffsets: $nodeOffsets)
            }
            .offset(model.pan)
            .scaleEffect(model.zoom, anchor: .topLeading)
       }
```